# How to update ember packages?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, bower

I have my old project that use Ember 2.8.

Now, I want to update all the packages and here is the updated package.json

```
{
  "name": "php-api-ember-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for php-api-ember-test goes here",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "~2.14.2",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.3.0",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-4": "^0.3.2",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.4.3",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.1.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.5.1",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "~2.14.9",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.0.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^4.5 || 6.* || >= 7.*"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this is bower.json

```
{
  "name": "php-api-ember-test",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~2.14.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.1"
  }
}
```

I was deleted the **bower_components** and **node_modules** folders and then run the command `npm install && bower install`.
After those install completed I run `ember init` and get this result.

```
Missing npm packages:
Package: ember-ajax
  * Specified: ^3.0.0
  * Installed: 2.5.6

Package: ember-cli-app-version
  * Specified: ^3.0.0
  * Installed: 1.0.1

Package: ember-cli-babel
  * Specified: ^6.3.0
  * Installed: 5.2.4

Package: ember-cli-htmlbars
  * Specified: ^2.0.1
  * Installed: 1.3.4

Package: ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile
  * Specified: ^0.4.3
  * Installed: 0.3.13

Package: ember-cli-qunit
  * Specified: ^4.1.0
  * Installed: 2.2.6

Package: ember-export-application-global
  * Specified: ^2.0.0
  * Installed: 1.1.1

Package: ember-load-initializers
  * Specified: ^1.0.0
  * Installed: 0.5.1

Package: ember-resolver
  * Specified: ^4.0.0
  * Installed: 2.1.1

Package: ember-welcome-page
  * Specified: ^3.0.0
  * Installed: 1.0.4

Run `npm install` to install missing dependencies.

An error occured in the constructor for ember-cli-dependency-checker
```

But I'm already run the `npm install` commands for many times.

How to update Ember packages?

Comment: Don't forget to clean the caches, too: `npm cache clean && bower cache clean`

Comment: Yes, after `npm cache clean && bower cache clean` and `npm install && bower install` I have to manually run `npm install --save-dev ember-load-initializers@1.0.0` and now it works!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official upgrade docs are here: [ember-cli upgrade](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/upgrading/). Details are in [release notes](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases).

First of all, there are some distinct steps:

1. Setting up the global ember-cli
2. Upgrading the project ember version
3. Upgrading the all other addons

You should better to do them step-by-step.

By the way, look all the release notes of the releases you've passed through. Because there may some differences. For example, for older versions (2.14, 2.13..) there were `bower cache clean` and `bower install` steps. For new versions (2.15), those steps are not necessary.

Comment: The ember-cli upgrade guide does not contain cache clean, with cache clean everything works fine. However thank you +1 :)

Comment: `npm cache clean` was written in previous releases. Such as: [2.13.1](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.13.1) I don't know why it was removed in recent releases.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use npm. Use yarn. It's faster, more secure and has better cache. It's also recommended as migration path from Bower (by Bower). Yarn is also recommended by Ember team instead of npm.

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with command I don't know how to use them without document. The document in ember website still use npm.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yarn` to selective package update

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```